# NestJS and TypeORM custom Many-to-Many relationship is returning only 1 result

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have 3 entities:

1. `order.entity.ts`
2. `pod.entity.ts`
3. `order-pod.entity.ts` - A custom many-to-many entity with extra properties that I need.

For each order in the database I have more than 1 pod associated with it in the order_pod table that has been created using the `order-pod.entity.ts`, but when I fetch the data from the repository, I am having 2 issues:

1. I am always getting only 1 pod object in the `Order.pods` array (even though I have much more than that)
2. The data is nested in a weird way and I would prefer each pod object to be flat

This is the result I am getting:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "customerFirstName": "Erez",
        "customerLastName": "H",
        "created_at": "2022-02-23",
        "totalQty": 1,
        "price": "12.99",
        "shippingCost": "9.99",
        "pods": [
            {
                "orderId": 1,
                "podId": 1,
                "quantity": 1,
                "pod": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Green Smoothie Pod",
                    "description": "A very nice description about the Green Smoothie Pod",
                    "weightInG": 23,
                    "color": "green",
                    "brand": "Tolive",
                    "imageURL": "https://i.ibb.co/0KR56HX/green-smoothie-pod.png",
                    "price": "84.00",
                    "calories": "0.00",
                    "protein": "12.00",
                    "sugar": "33.00",
                    "carbohydrates": "60.00",
                    "sodium": "24.00",
                    "cholesterol": "0.00",
                    "totalFats": "1.00"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is the `getOrders` method I am using:
`order.service.ts`:

```
  async getOrders: Promise<Order[]> {
    const allOrders = await this.ordersRepository.find({
      relations: ['pods'],
    });
    return allOrders;
  }
```

This is my `order.entity.ts`

```
@Entity()
export class Order {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  id: number;

  @Column()
  customerFirstName: string;

  @Column()
  customerLastName: string;

  @Column('date')
  created_at: Date;

  @Column()
  totalQty: number;

  @Column('decimal', { precision: 5, scale: 2 })
  price: number;

  @Column('decimal', { precision: 5, scale: 2 })
  shippingCost: number;

  @OneToMany(() => OrderPod, (orderPod) => orderPod.pod)
  pods: Pod[];
}
```

`pod.entity.ts`:

```
@Entity()
export class Pod {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  description: string;

  @Column()
  weightInG: number;

  @Column()
  color: string;

  @Column()
  brand: string;

  @Column()
  imageURL: string;

  @Column('decimal', { precision: 5, scale: 2 })
  price: number;

  @Column('decimal', { precision: 5, scale: 2 })
  calories: number;

  @Column('decimal', { precision: 5, scale: 2 })
  protein: number;

  @Column('decimal', { precision: 5, scale: 2 })
  sugar: number;

  @Column('decimal', { precision: 5, scale: 2 })
  carbohydrates: number;

  @Column('decimal', { precision: 5, scale: 2 })
  sodium: number;

  @Column('decimal', { precision: 5, scale: 2 })
  cholesterol: number;

  @Column('decimal', { precision: 5, scale: 2 })
  totalFats: number;

  @OneToMany(() => OrderPod, (orderPod) => orderPod.order)
  orders: Order[];
}
```

and my order-pod.entity.ts

```
@Entity()
export class OrderPod {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  orderId: number;

  @PrimaryColumn()
  podId: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Order, (order) => order.pods)
  order: Order;

  @ManyToOne(() => Pod, (pod) => pod.orders, { eager: true })
  pod: Pod;

  @Column({ type: 'int' })
  quantity: number;
}
```

Comment: Hey did you ever figure this out? Im on a similar path to you?